# Altering an existing column to make it unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 'Users' table where I want to make the 'Phone' column unique. Currently the 'PhoneNumber' column allow null. I'm using the following script.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users
ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_PhoneNumber 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (PhoneNumber)
```

The problem is, there is 300+ rows in the 'Users' table. Half of them have a Null value. When I run the script it says complete successfully. However after refreshing the table constraints in Management studio, the constraint did not appear and is not applied to that column when adding a new user.

Note: If I try to run the script again, I get a duplicate error, like the constraint already exist.

Anyone know what I need to do in order to get the column unique?

Comment: If 2008+ use a unique filtered index. If 2000-2005 use an indexed view.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Martin, thank you for your suggestion. Sorry I should have mentionned I use MSSQL 2008 R2. I will try the filtered index suggestion.

Comment: ...Why aren't users allowed to share a phone number?  My two parents live in one house, with one physical land-line (phone number).  What happens if they both register?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "indexes" in `sp_help` procedure (assuming SQL Server):
`sp_help 'dbo.Users'`.
"Unique constraint" is actually unique index. If you create ordinary unique index, then max one `null` value is allowed in the field. To exclude nulls from the check, you need to create unique filtered index, like so:

`create unique index Unique_PhoneNumber  on dbo.Users(PhoneNumber) where (PhoneNumber is not null)`

Comment: Thanks for your solution frikozoid. When I execute the command, I get the same result about duplicates :(

Comment: @Mario It's because you already have `Unique_PhoneNumber` on this table. Drop it first.

Comment: I did drop the index then ran the script to create the index again. Here is the error message: The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Users' and the index name 'idx_NetworkUserLogin_notnull'. The duplicate key value is (). The table was badly designed having a varchar(50) as PK could it be just that?